# Answering own trivial questions to harvest reputation

Tags: discussion

I came across this question: 
[Replacement for deprecated sizeWithFont: in iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897896/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfont-in-ios-7)

This guy answered his own trivial question directly after he posted the question. Are these practices allowed or should they be flagged?

Comment: Flagged as what? Do you know a valid reason to flag the post?
Sure, the question may be trivial, but enough users have had the same problem to result in over 250 upvotes on that answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> This guy answered his own trivial question directly after he posted the question

What that user has done is perfectly acceptable - they've answered their own question. In fact Stack Exchange explicitly enable that feature with a little checkbox under the question as you type it, so they both get posted together.

So now that we know it's okay to do, the only critique left to answer is that you consider the question to be trivial and the user is harvesting rep from it.

Stack Exchange do not adjudicate what *trivial* is - that is done by the people who read the question and answer and then vote on it. With the amount of up votes this question/answer has, I would suspect that many people have found it useful, therefore it is not trivial. You might know the answer, but lots of others don't.

Answer (score 5):

I would say that any question that gets over 82,000 views in a year, 155 upvotes, and an answer with 268 upvotes is a valuable addition to the site.

Whether they answered their own question or somebody else answered it is unrelated to the usefulness and quality of the question and answer.

In general, asking an on-topic question and giving a useful answer are both practices that are allowed. Neither should be flagged.

Sometimes, people will hit "gold mine" questions that seem silly or trivial. Just remember that these kinds of questions typically add a lot of value to the site and are useful to many people. These are good things.